# If $\phi(x)$ satisfies conditions of Rolle's theorem, then answer the following questions

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f(x)$ is a function such that it is thrice differentiable in $(a,b)$. Consider a function

$$\phi(x)=f(b)-f(x)-(b-x)f'(x)-\frac{(b-x)^2}{2}f''(x)-(b-x)^3 \lambda$$ and $\phi(x)$ follows all conditions of Rolle's Theorem on $[a.b]$

**Ques** If there exists some $c \in (a,b)$ such that $\phi '(c)=0$ and $$f(b)=f(a)+(b-a)f'(a)+\frac{(b-a)^2}{2}f''(a)+ \mu (b-a)^3 f'''(c)$$, then find the value of $\mu$.

Using

$\phi(x)=f(b)-f(x)-(b-x)f'(x)-\frac{(b-x)^2}{2}f''(x)-(b-x)^3 \lambda$

we have
$f(b)=\phi(x)+f(x)+(b-x)f'(x)+\frac{(b-x)^2}{2}f''(x)+(b-x)^3 \lambda$

Then set $x=a$

$f(b)=\phi(a)+f(a)+(b-a)f'(a)+\frac{(b-a)^2}{2}f''(a)+(b-a)^3 \lambda$

But now I am not able to use conditions of Rolle's Theorem i.e.  $\phi(a)=\phi(b)$ and $\phi'(c)=0$ for atleast one $c \in (a,b)$ Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Could $\mu = \lambda / f'''(c)$ be an acceptable answer for the first question?

Comment: @GuachoPerez Options are constant value.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to answer your first question: First by actually computing $\phi'$ you will find that $\phi'(c)=0$ implies that $f'''(c)=6\lambda$. Now observe that $\phi(b)=0$ and therefore by the condition of Rolles theorem $\phi(a)=0$ but that means:

$$f(b)-f(a)-(b-a)f'(a)-\dfrac{(b-a)^2}{2}f''(a)=(b-a)^3\lambda. $$

But now the first question imposes the condition

$$ f(b)-f(a)-(b-a)f'(a)-\dfrac{(b-a)^2}{2}f''(a)=\mu(b-a)^3f'''(c).$$

Using what we have computed we conclude that

$$\mu(b-a)^3f'''(c)=\mu(b-a)^36\lambda=(b-a)^3\lambda. $$

And therefore $\mu = \dfrac{1}{6}$.